# Head-tracking and mouse control

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm trying to control the mouse using the Head-tracking with Kinect.
I think it's possible, but still haven't managed it to work.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AwesomeFaceTracking
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    KinectSensor kinectSensor;
    FaceTracker faceTracker;
    private byte[] colorPixelData;
    private short[] depthPixelData;
    private Skeleton[] skeletonData;

    [DllImport("user32")]

    public static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;

    [DllImport("user32.dll",
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwflags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // For a KinectSensor to be detected, we can plug it in after the application has been started.
        KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
        // Or it's already plugged in, so we will look for it.
        var kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
        if (kinect != null)
        {
            OpenKinect(kinect);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the StatusChanged event of the KinectSensors control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="Microsoft.Kinect.StatusChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
        {
            OpenKinect(e.Sensor);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the kinect.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newSensor">The new sensor.</param>
    private void OpenKinect(KinectSensor newSensor)
    {
        kinectSensor = newSensor;

        // Initialize all the necessary streams:
        // - ColorStream with default format
        // - DepthStream with Near mode
        // - SkeletonStream with tracking in NearReange and Seated mode.

        kinectSensor.ColorStream.Enable();

        //kinectSensor.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Near;
        kinectSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution80x60Fps30);

        //kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = true;
        //kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
        kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters() { Correction = 0.5f, JitterRadius = 0.05f, MaxDeviationRadius = 0.05f, Prediction = 0.5f, Smoothing = 0.5f });

        // Listen to the AllFramesReady event to receive KinectSensor's data.
        kinectSensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(kinectSensor_AllFramesReady);

        // Initialize data arrays
        colorPixelData = new byte[kinectSensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];
        depthPixelData = new short[kinectSensor.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
        skeletonData = new Skeleton[6];

        // Starts the Sensor
        kinectSensor.Start();

        // Initialize a new FaceTracker with the KinectSensor
        faceTracker = new FaceTracker(kinectSensor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the AllFramesReady event of the kinectSensor control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="Microsoft.Kinect.AllFramesReadyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void kinectSensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve each single frame and copy the data
        using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorImageFrame == null)
                return;
            colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorPixelData);
        }

        using (DepthImageFrame depthImageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (depthImageFrame == null)
                return;
            depthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(depthPixelData);
        }

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame == null)
                return;
            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonData);
        }

        // Retrieve the first tracked skeleton if any. Otherwise, do nothing.
        var skeleton = skeletonData.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked);
        if (skeleton == null)
            return;

        // Make the faceTracker processing the data.
        FaceTrackFrame faceFrame = faceTracker.Track(kinectSensor.ColorStream.Format, colorPixelData,
                                          kinectSensor.DepthStream.Format, depthPixelData,
                                          skeleton);



        // If a face is tracked, then we can use it.
        if (faceFrame.TrackSuccessful)
        {
            // Retrieve only the Animation Units coeffs.
            var AUCoeff = faceFrame.GetAnimationUnitCoefficients();

            var jawLowerer = AUCoeff[AnimationUnit.JawLower];
            jawLowerer = jawLowerer < 0 ? 0 : jawLowerer;
            MouthScaleTransform.ScaleY = jawLowerer * 5 + 0.1;
            MouthScaleTransform.ScaleX = (AUCoeff[AnimationUnit.LipStretcher] + 1);

            LeftBrow.Y = RightBrow.Y = (AUCoeff[AnimationUnit.BrowLower]) * 40;

            RightBrowRotate.Angle = (AUCoeff[AnimationUnit.BrowRaiser] * 20);
            LeftBrowRotate.Angle = -RightBrowRotate.Angle;

            CanvasRotate.Angle = faceFrame.Rotation.Z;
            CanvasTranslate.X = faceFrame.Translation.X;
            CanvasTranslate.Y = faceFrame.Translation.Y;

            Joint ScaledJoint = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head];

            //Funcionando!!!
            int topofscreen = Convert.ToInt32(faceFrame.Translation.Y);
            int leftofscreen = Convert.ToInt32(faceFrame.Translation.X);

            SetCursorPos(leftofscreen, topofscreen);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

If i use the topofscreen and leftofscreen, setting them as faceFrame.Rotation.Y and X, it works when i nod my head to the right or left.
But what i'm trying to do is to control the mouse when i move my head in all possible angles, like looking up, right...

Any tips on how to do it?

**UPDATE**

Am i going in the wrong direction here? I mean, should i try to track, and control the mouse, with a specific point of the face, like the eyes or nose? If so, is there a easy way to do it?

Comment: You know, the eyes will be automatically looking at the cursor, and the head automatically goes where the eyes are looking, so it would probably be unnatural and slow. Cool, yes, but wouldn't be my choice of interface.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan he wasnt asking for your opinion, just how to do it.

Comment: @user1739957, it actually isn't his opinion.  There are multiple usability studies on eye tracking that show a person is inclined to watch the cursor instead of objects on the screen.  Such an interface would be combersome, unnatural and ill-advised.  It is a cool concept - I'll have a look at the code soon, but I would not recommend this in anything outside an academic environment.

Comment: @Pedro Boga - What is the `FaceTracker` you are using?  It is not clear to me from your code what values `faceFrame.Translation.X` and `Y` are in relation to.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey The FACETRACKER is Microsoft's default. It's a huge code, so i used pastebin to show it: [FaceTracker](http://pastebin.com/9D5cXSrD) . This answer your question?

Comment: @YoryeNathan Yes, actually this is just for academic purposes. Looking to what can be done with it. But thanks for the opinion.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you, I just wanted to point some stuff out, to help you, just in case you haven't thought of them yourself.

Comment: @PedroBoga - I can not access your link (work firewall).  Is this code that is available in the SDK Developer Toolkit Examples?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Hers the link for the facetracking, without the mouse control attempts [FaceTracking](http://www.renauddumont.be/en/2012/kinect-sdk-1-5-face-tracking-en-csharp)